# Regex Cant Search All

Tags: regex, vb.net

So basically consider this example:

```
google123         

   apples

   doodle1234
```

I have used look arounds

```
(?<=google123)([^\n]*\n[\s*\w+])+(?=doodle1234)
```

Unfortunately for me it just works with

```
google123         

   apples

doodle1234
```

Note:The space "   doodle1234" is not recognised by it from the first example.It only recognises "doodle1234" .

Search output must be apples

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong here:

```
[\s*\w+]
```

(You're including asterisks in the character class.) Instead:

```
\s*\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `[\s*\w+]` to `[\s*\w+]+` or `[\s*\w+]*`:

explanation:

> ***`*`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or ***more*** times.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or ***more*** times.

and your `regex` can be like this:

```
(?<=google123)([^\n]*\n[\s*\w+]*)+(?=doodle1234)
```

or you can use `*?` or `+?`:

> ***`*?`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or more times, but **as few times as possible**.
>
> ***`+?`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times, but **as few times as possible**.

Comment: it is working but this is selecting everything after doodle1234 until another doodle1234 at the end

Comment: ah yes is not greedy anymore